# Red Box After Upvote

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, error-message

On serverfault, I got a redbox popup (like the one when you try to accept your answer) right after an upvote on a question, but I had already hit back before it popped up and I had time to read it.  Anyone know what that might have said? I believe it had the word denied in it.

The question might have been: [https://serverfault.com/questions/78695/winter-and-summer-time-switch-without-a-break-in-the-timeline/78699#78699](https://serverfault.com/questions/78695/winter-and-summer-time-switch-without-a-break-in-the-timeline/78699) . Of course, I can not confirm or deny that I did in fact anonymously up vote that question.

Comment: I thought I was going to start getting movies sent to me for upvoting when I read the title.  Imagine my disappointment...

Comment: ...http://www.redbox.com/

Comment: This is still an issue, the answer that was corrected is that it happens to them too. Going back is a workaround, not a fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those pop up from time to time for me.  They're usually the "An error has occurred" box and sometimes the vote is cast, sometimes not.  Usually I'll just go back and refresh the question to make sure my vote took.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is described here:
[Vote + refresh causes an erroneous error box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56793/vote-refresh-causes-an-erroneous-error-box)

It can be reproduced 100% of the times: just upvote something and immediately reload the page. (You can undo the vote later)

So I just wonder, don't we want to fix this minor bug?

Comment: no, since reloading the page will interrupt the ajax request.. this is like proposing we "fix" a bug where someone pulls the network cord out of their computer in the middle of a request..

Comment: But the request goes through anyway and the action succeeds.. isn't it possible to detect when user reload the page and in such case suppress the red message?