# Vote + refresh causes an erroneous error box

Tags: bug, voting, error-message

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Red Box After Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27463/red-box-after-upvote)

If I vote on a question/answer and immediately refresh the page, the `An error has occurred - please retry your request` box appears (until the page refreshes), even though my vote has gone through successfully. This might be a rare-enough edge case to not bother fixing, but it's consistently reproducible

Comment: This can also happen if you navigate away from the page immediately after casting the vote, such as by clicking the logo. I don't really think this is something to worry about - few people have any good reason to refresh right after casting a vote (most people like to actually get confirmation the vote went through, after all), and the age-old adage of "Don't do it!" applies well to stop seeing the error message.

Comment: @Grace I generally look at the answers on a new question, upvote the best one(s), and immediately refresh to see what others have been posted, so I run into this semi-often, but it's not a big deal to ignore it

Comment: I get this a lot, especially in the case that @Grace notes.

Comment: Well, this is going to get closed as a duplicate of a long-abandoned bug, so I guess I'll continue ignoring them