# Click Vote Up a question, then click on the "Questions" link and an error occurs

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Vote + refresh causes an erroneous error box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56793/vote-refresh-causes-an-erroneous-error-box)
>   [Red Box After Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27463/red-box-after-upvote)

I have found when clicking vote up for a question in stackoverflow, then click the "Questions" link after, I get an orange "An error occurred, please try again."

This happens quite often for me, hopefully it is nothing I am doing wrong!

I am using Firefox (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13)

I would like to raise this to make sure if it is a problem that it does not affect people's experience with StackOverflow.